# bug where too short title was posted

Tags: bug

This question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863013/boolean-equals

I cannot remove tag because I get error "title must be at least 15 characters long." Then how was it posted in the first place?

Comment: Quality-Assurance mechanisms came into place after questions were posted. So, it is common to edit a question and not be able to save it immediately. Just fix the title in this case.

Comment: @BrianWebster it's strange this isn't checked on posting.

Comment: Think of it this way. On January 1st, 12-character titles are legal. On February 1st, the rule is changed and 12-character titles become illegal. On March 1st, you edit the question and try to save it -- you will have to change the title because the title used to be legal, but isn't anymore.